# GitHub not adding whole folder content?

Tags: github, master, push, commit

I have w problem with pushing whole folder with its content to my repository on GitHub.

I use the following:

```
$ cd principal 
$ git add * 
$ git push
```

Where `principal` is the name of folder containing two other folders (`Z1`, `Z2`) and their content. 
Then I visit the GitHub and see:

[image]

There is definitelly sth wrong with `Z1` folder - I expected to see sth `openable` (like `Z3`) as this folder is a java project containing `src` and other folders. What is happeing?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add

Comment: possible duplicate of ["nothing to commit (working directory clean)" when a folder has been added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130633/nothing-to-commit-working-directory-clean-when-a-folder-has-been-added)

Comment: Sorry for the migration: this has nothing to do with Superuser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [grey folder is a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19131821/6309)

That means `Z1` is a nested git repo added in your main repo as a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.